# Why is "'access content' permission is required" when accessing nodes with _format=json?

Tags: nodes, 10

After upgrading to D10, authenticated users cannot access `/node/{id}` rest endpoint and images.

`View published content` permission is enabled and I can see in the logs that I am authenticated. Clearing cache didn't help either.

[image]

I'm also getting access denied on images too.

[image]

I don't know what permission I'm missing.

[image]

Edit: I can see everything perfectly fine on the browser. Images, `/node/{id}` and `/node/{id}?_format=json` all good. However, that is probably because of cookies. I don't have a way of testing with oauth2 directly on the browser so I suspect the issue is related to access tokens.

Comment: I noticed `_format=json` in the query string. Are there additional details needed in the Question?

Comment: @cilefen yes it's the api. Not web. In fact, I can view it fine the page, rest resource and the images perfectly fine on the browser.